# Spline in VTK looks distorted

Tags: python, python-2.7, vtk

I am using the `vtk` package for python 2.7 to create some 3-dimensional stuff that I want to export to an `.stl`. Part of the geometry are sine waves with adjustable amplitudes. Here is my problem: When I generate the splines from point data (basically a point in every max, min and turning point) it does not look uniform!

This is what the spline looks like:

[image]

You can see that the middle amplitude looks kinda okay, while the rest is clearly distorted towards the center

Basically I only want the middle part to look like a perfect sine, because I cut away the remainder anyway.

When I use another program (Autodesk Inventor) to create splines manually from the same point data it creates a uniform sine wave. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Sorry for not providing any code, but I will give you the steps I do:

1. add points to `vtkPoints` object
2. create `vtkParametricSpline` with `vtkPoints` as input
3. use `vtkSplineFilter` to get a finer resolution of the spline
4. use `vtkTubeFilter` to create volume
5. use `vtkClipClosedSurface` to cut away what is not needed

Comment: If you need to get this resolved asap, just add way more precalculated points, that are supposed to be located on the sine. This does not resolve the issue, but will most likely help you with *this* problem.

Comment: Thanks! That would indeed provide a quick fix, but in the end I want to have the geometry as precise as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, parameterizing the line with a cosine function was the only way to avoid the weird spline behaviour. I tried avoiding it before, because it seemed over-engineered, but it turned out to be the better way.

New algorithm:

cosine function -> `vtkPoints`-> `vtkLineSource` -> `vtkTubeFilter`